# CPU time limit error

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, performance, cpulimit

I have one child object on account having lookup relationship, I want to update the average of some fields of child to parent, for this I wrote one after insert trigger on child. on doing bulk load I'm getting cpu time limit exception. How can I make this code more bulkify?

below is my code:

```
public void updateAccount(List<CustomObject> CustomObjectList){

    Set<Id> accIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    for(CustomObject per : CustomObjectList){
        accIdSet.add(per.Account__c);
    }

    List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, (Select Id,Field1,Field2,Field3,
                                        Field4,Field5,Field6,
                                        Field7,Field8,Field9,Field910 from CustomObjectList__r ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Account where Id IN : accIdSet LIMIT 1000];

    List<Account> accountList = new List<account>();                                    

    for(Account acc : accList){

        if(acc.CustomObjectList__r.size() > 0){

            for(CustomObject per : acc.CustomObjectList__r){
                Account accObj = new Account();
                accObj.Id = acc.Id;
                accObj.Field1 = per.Field1;
                accObj.Field2 = per.Field2;
                accObj.Field3 = per.Field3;
                accObj.Field4 = per.Field4;
                accObj.Field5 = per.Field5;
                accObj.Field6 = per.Field6;
                accObj.Field7 = per.Field7;
                accObj.Field8 = per.Field8;
                accObj.Field9 = per.Field9;
                accObj.Field910 = per.Field910;

                accountList.add(accObj);
            }  
        }
    }

    update accountList;


    List<AggregateResult> accAverageList = [Select Account__c,AVG(Field11) avg1,AVG(Field22) avg2,
                                                AVG(Field33) avg3,AVG(Field44) avg4,
                                                AVG(Field55) avg5,AVG(Field66) avg6,
                                                AVG(Field77) avg7,AVG(Field88) avg8,AVG(Field99) avg9,
                                                AVG(Field100) avg99 from CustomObject where Account__c IN : accIdSet GROUP BY Account__c LIMIT 1000];
    List<Account> accountAvgList = new List<account>(); 

    For(AggregateResult agr : accAverageList){
        Account accObj = new Account();
        accObj.Id = (Id) agr.get('Account__c');
        accObj.Field11 = Integer.valueOf(agr.get('avg1'));
        accObj.Field22 = Integer.valueOf(agr.get('avg2'));
        accObj.Field33 = Integer.valueOf(agr.get('avg3'));
        accObj.Field44 = Integer.valueOf(agr.get('avg4'));
        accObj.Field55 = Integer.valueOf(agr.get('avg5'));
        accObj.Field66 = Integer.valueOf(agr.get('avg6'));
        accObj.Field77 = Integer.valueOf(agr.get('avg7'));
        accObj.Field88 = Integer.valueOf(agr.get('avg8'));
        accObj.Field99 = Integer.valueOf(agr.get('avg9'));
        accObj.Field100 = Integer.valueOf(agr.get('avg99'));

        accountAvgList.add(accObj);
    }   

    update accountAvgList;                                  
}
```

Comment: Use a nested map to reduce the lookup time. The nested for loop is consuming large process time and has very poor performance (e.g. 100 records by 100 records is 10,000 executions of code

Comment: can you please share some example? what do you mean by nested map

Comment: Take a look at this post (https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/fixing-a-common-cause-of-system-limitexception-apex-cpu-time-limit-exceeded/). Great piece of writing!

Comment: Not sure why do you need the first part of the code? Why you are copying fields1-10 from the custom_object to the account?

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a huge time savings by instantiating your records using `name=value` pairs:

**Slow**

```
Account record = new Account();
record.id = someValue;
record.Field1 = someValue1;
// etc.
accountList.add(record);
```

**Fast**

```
accountList.add(new Account(
    Id = someValue,
    Field1 = someValue1
    // etc.
));
```

You have a couple sections of your code where this pattern will greatly reduce your CPU Time.

The general application of this strategy would look something like the following:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>([/*first query*/]);
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [/*aggregate query*/])
{
    Account existingRecord = accounts.get((Id)aggregate.get('Account__c'));
    ChildObject__c child = existingRecord.Children__r[0];
    accountList.add(new Account(
        Id = existingRecord.Id,
        AggregateField1 = aggregate.get('Field1'),
        AggregateField2 = aggregate.get('Field2'),
        Field1 = child.Field1,
        Field2 = child.Field2
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, Even after changing it, I'm getting same error